# How do I make these changes to my directory from the command line? (RoR)

Tags: bash, command-line

Currently our post resources are nested under topics. We should organize our `posts_controller` and `post views` in the same manner. Make the following directory changes: Try to make these changes from your command line.

```
app/controllers/posts_controller.rb -> app/controllers/topics/posts_controller.rb
```

How do I make the changes using the command line?

Comment: I tried using mv but it says mv: cannot move `app/controllers/posts_controller.rb' to `app/controllers/topics/posts_controller.rb': No such file or directory

Comment: can you check if the file `app/controllers/topics/posts_controller.rb` is exist in current folder?  `ls -l app/controllers/topics/posts_controller.rb`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ mkdir app/controllers/topics
$ mv app/controllers/posts_controller.rb app/controllers/topics/posts_controller.rb
```

Generically, you'd want to use `mkdir -p` in case app/controllers/topics exists already.